# what could be the possible nuisance variables for this experiment?

Tags: r, experiment-design

I'm new to statistic and I'm considering the experiment of calculation ability between people who customarily paying in cash and paying in cashless.
Hypothesis here is "People who customarily paying in cash has better calculation ability than people who customarily paying in cashless".

The question is, what could be the possible nuisance variables for this model?
I think that participant's mathematical background might be a nuisance. Is this adequate? any other ideas?

[edit]

in this experiment, dependent variable is calculation ability and independent variables are paying in cash and paying in cashless.

Then, how many models do I have to run during model comparison?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not see an experiment here. What is the treatment? Are you going to force some people to pay with cash or cashless and then assess their calculation ability?

I suspect you are just trying to fit a model of calculation ability with the preferred method of payment as a covariate. In that case, possible nuisance variables would be age or years of schooling. We have a strong reason to believe calculation ability tends to improve with education; however, you are not interested in the effect of education.

Comment: "Are you going to force some people to pay with cash or cashless and then assess their calculation ability?" -yes. In this situation, we're going to force participants to pay with cash or cashless for a certain period.

Comment: "In that case, possible nuisance variables would be age or years of schooling." - then, how many models do I have to run?

Comment: One model. You fit one model that fits the experimental design.